# How to play videos one after another in a loop from internal folder? I have many videos in my DNB/Videos folder

Tags: android-videoview

How to play videos one after another in a loop from internal folder?
 I have many videos in my DNB/Videos folder

```
videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    Uri video = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DNB/Videos/i.mp4");

    videoView.setVideoPath(video.toString());
    videoView.start();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener (new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an array with the names of all my videos. And then i created a method that returns a new name, iteratively.

Then, on **videoView.setOnCompletionListener(.....)** i set my method to start displaying the new video based in it's new name.

Comment: if you want i can post my code, but i think it won't be of much help cause you'll need to understand the rest of the code.. but, to help you, that's my logic. Hope it helps xD